# What governs the number of unawaited asynchronous tasks in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

Writing a processing method, takes an item off a queue, processes it, next item, and so on.

It's not fast enough because sometimes processing has to wait for network I/O.

Synchronously, it is `await ProcessThisMessage(message)`.

If I change it to `ProcessThisMessage(message)` (which is `async Task`) instead (fire & forget), what's the behaviour for if lots of these stack up?

Is it constrained by the memory and CPU of the machine? Or is there a hard-limit such as a maximum threadpool size?

Basically, I'm wondering if C# will take care of itself by naturally limiting and just blocking when the maximum is reached, or if I need to manually do something in case they build up and reach the limit.

Comment: This might be an interesting read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Interesting, perhaps I can just use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and it'll take care of it all

Comment: or you'll saturate the thread pool... :) In the past, I've used a bounded pipe (circular buffer) for this - when it reaches the end of the pipe, it starts awaiting things before it overwrites the next incomplete item; so you get pipelining, but with a simple max-dop

Comment: Yes, that's what I was going to do, but I thought rather than roll my own there could be a solution out there. I looked at SemaphoreSlim and the above QueueUserWorkItem, not really sure yet. Apparently QueueUserWorkItem waits for a Thread, so if the ThreadPool has a limit it won't trash the machine. I don't know how many can wait. Ideally I'd want the ability to timeout though or over time threads could get stuck, even at one a week that'd cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

> It's not fast enough

The normal solution is to add another processor instance. Possibly on another machine, possibly on the same machine. I've worked with some processors that are multithreaded, with each thread independently taking from the queue; and I've worked with some processors that are scaled to multiple machines.

"Fire and forget" is *not* a normal solution, because "fire and forget" means "I don't care if this fails", and usually you *do* care if it fails.

That said:

> Is it constrained by the memory and CPU of the machine? Or is there a hard-limit such as a maximum threadpool size?

Asynchronous tasks are only constrained by memory. Each "fire and forget" task will exist until it completes (or until the application exits, of course). There isn't any kind of limit built in to .NET; your app will just run out of memory.